# Embedding base64 encoded images in XML files (android-java)

Tags: java, android, xml, base64

I'm working on a project and for the theme delivery system ( if I may say so ), I wanna put everything from the widgets layout to any necessary images in an xml file. Needless to say, the images must be encoded in base64.(or is there another way???) Now the question is considering we're in mobile devices realm, will there be any problem regarding memory or decoding medium sized images ( maybe at most 50KiB ) or any other issue?

a hypothetical example of the xml theme would be:

```
<?xml version whatever?>
<theme>
     <positionx id="foo">5</positionx>
     <positiony id="foo">6</positiony>
     <icon id="foo">BASE64_ENCODED_IMAGE_HERE</icon>
     <positionx id="bar">5</positionx>
     <positiony id="bar">6</positiony>
     <icon id="bar">BASE64_ENCODED_IMAGE_2_HERE</icon>
</theme>
```

NOTE: The final theme is not entirely like this at all. this is just an example for you guys to know what I mean. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you mean here `I wanna put everything from the widgets layout to any necessary images in an xml file`. Could you expand a little your question?

Comment: I guess a much better (and faster) approach would be to put only image links inside the XML and then download them when needed. It's generally not a good practice to store binary data in Strings

Comment: @Droidman What your saying(remote images) is really good, but unfortunately for my usecase it's not ideal at all. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base64 carries a 6 bit payload in a char, meaning you need 4/3 the size for a text representation; 50 KiB * 4/3 = 67 KiB.

However an XML DOM is on itself heavy, so though feasible you might not want the extra resources, conversion need (speed and double memory for both text and binary result).

Even if my conclusion is more or less negative, your model driven approach is certainly a good idea. You might generate from the original XML your run-time data.